# experiments and probabilities

Tags: probability

If I perform an experiment with 60 trials and I decide to triple the trials to 180, why would i get a probability closer to the true probability with 180 trials compared to 60 trials?

I feel like this is not always true. Any ideas?

Comment: In principle, more trials may indeed produce a worse result. Suppose the probability of heads is exactly $1/2$. Then with probability $1/2$, two trials will produce an exact answer. It is quite unlikely that $200$ tosses will produce exactly $100$ heads.

Answer (score 0):

In reality the more the number of trials you do the more precise your probability will be. 
But if there are equi likely outcomes ( the way we deal in maths) then number of trials won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a **law of large numbers** applies in the situation you describe. The average of $n$ trials gets closer to the mean $\mu$ as $n$ gets larger.

Maybe you are thinking of an example like flipping a coin. The proportion of heads in a number of trials gets closer to the actual probability of heads as the number of trials grows.

It makes intuitive sense if you think about it... One way to think about what probability means is that it tells you the proportion of trials you expect to give a certain outcome.

Note that you won't always get an answer closer to the expected mean/probability if you increase the number of trials. The jaw of large numbers of a statement about a random process. It is possible that if you get 50 heads out of 100 trials as expected, but that the next 100 trials are all tails. Thus moving away from the probability. But as you increase your number of trials, it becomes much less likely to be very far from the true probability.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a fair coin. If we flip it once, we will either get heads or tails, and our *experimental* probability is $1$ for either heads or tails (whichever it may be). But we know that since the coin is fair, each face must have a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of landing up. So we do more trials. We can record the probability *of* the experimental probability matching the theoretical (actual) probability by using a binomial distribution count. For $1$ coin, the odds are $0$ that we get an accurate representation. (It turns out this us also true for any odd number of flips.) For $100$ coins, the odds are $\dbinom{100}{50} \times \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100},$ which is about $8\%.$ This is small, but a large percentage of the outcomes will be close to the $50-50$ split. The more trials, the better!